# How to know the number of waiting tasks count on any app server in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

How can we know the no. of tasks that are waiting for processing on task server/app server in Marklogic.
I can only see the max limit and no. of requests are processing right now. But I didn't find any option to know the no. of tasks that are waiting.

Anyone please help.

I tried with different manage APIs to get the info. But didn't find any information related to waiting tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in the Task Server Queue Size metric.

You can view the Task Server's Queue Size in Monitoring History. Go to the Servers detail page, and it is the last panel under Task Server. That data is pulled from the Meters database. If you open F12 and watch the network calls, you can see that it fetches it from a Manage endpoint, and see that it's hitting  [`manage/v2/servers?view=metrics`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/servers@view=metrics)

A generic request looks like:
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers?view=metrics

You can specifically ask just for the `queue-size` metric and for it to be in `json` format:

http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers?view=metrics&server-metrics=queue-size&format=json

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin UI, go to

```
    Configure > Groups > _group_name_ > Task Server
```

and look at the status tab.  It shows also the queue size.